Enabling Envers auditing between nested transactions
I'm working with Spring Boot and Hibernate Envers, and I'm trying to set up a specific transaction and auditing behavior.
Here's my current setup:
@Service
public class MyService {
    
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void parentMethod() {
        childMethod1();
        childMethod2();
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    private void childMethod1() {
        // Creates some records that will be updated in childMethod2
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    private void childMethod2() {
        // Updates records created in childMethod1
    }
}

What I'm trying to achieve
childMethod1 and childMethod2 should run in separate transactions
I need to capture Envers audit records for updates made in childMethod2 to the records created in childMethod1. If childMethod2 fails, childMethod1 should be rolled back as well
What I've tried
Added propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW to childMethod2 hoping it would create a new transaction and capture the audit records, but this didn't solve the issue.
Considered using REQUIRES_NEW on both child methods and manually handling the rollback of childMethod1 if childMethod2 fails, but this approach doesn't provide true atomicity, so it's not a viable solution.
The transactions appear to be working correctly in terms of isolation, but still no audit records are being generated
Current behavior
The transactions seem to be working, but I'm not getting the Envers audit records for the updates made in childMethod2
The rollback behavior works as expected
How can I ensure Envers captures the audit records between these nested transactions?

There are no nested transactions. Internal method calls don't pass through the transactional proxy, so the @Transactional on the private methods are useless. Even if the methods would be public it wouldn't work as it is an internal method call. You cannot have 2 seperate transactions and while committed 1 rolback the all. Persisted and committedc is persisted and committed.

Thanks @M.Deinum In that case, is there a way to enable envers auditing in the middle of a transaction so that I get audit records for the updates that happen in childMethod2?

Not that I'm aware of, it is a single transaction so it is all or nothing. You can try to flush in the childMethod1. Point is why should it see updates as they are just part of 1 tx set.

Hmm I think the best approach in this case would be to use single transaction and populate the envers audit logs manually. Since that will also fall under the transaction, it should all be rolled back if anything fails. Thanks @M.Deinum

But why do you want to have the updates as separate records? Starting to manually mess around with the envers audit logs might not be the best idea. I would first try the flushing in the first method as that will synchronize the changes to the database (without committing them).

@M.Deinum I am tracking some draft updates - each update means we clone the latest draft version (childfunction1 - this should create ADD audit records) and then update the cloned draft (this should create MOD audit records) (draft here refers to multiple records with the same draftMetadataId). But since all of this happens inside one transaction I dont get separate ADD and MOD audit records - just a bunch of ADD records at the end of the transaction. I also tried manually flushing before I call childFunction2 but that also did not work like I wanted (MOD records were not getting created).

I am now also considering using a separate table instead of the audit table for this since I just need to store the timestamps for when the change was made as that keeps auditing clean and also serves my use-case.

You must be doing something weird if what you stating doesn't result in an ADD and MOD as you are changing an existing record (assuming that that already existed, if not it isn't a MOD rightfully and just an ADD). If you want further assistence please show some actual code of what you are doing instead of showing some made up dummy code.
